# queryParams vs HttpParams in Anglar

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I just now figured out, we can construct Query String paramater URL using "queryParams" and HttpParams - below are the examples

```
goProducts() {
  this.router.navigate(
    ['/products'],
    { queryParams: { 'pageNumber': {page}, 'price-range': {itemsPerPage} } }
  );
}
```

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('pageNumber', page);
params = params.append('pageSize', itemsPerPage);
```

Which is the best method to use?
Tried to figure out the differences but I couldn't figure out much from the internet.

Tried to find the differences.

Comment: From the documentation (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams): An HTTP request/response body that represents serialized parameters, per the MIME type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So `HttpParams` is for form requests with body, e.g. `POST`. `queryParams` are added to the URL. Usually used in `GET` requests. Which approach is better, depends on what you are doing. I think for pagination the `queryParams` approach suits better, because you are _getting_ stuff from the server. If you save or update objects, `HttpParams` might be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Both methods - using **queryParams** and **HttpParams** - can be used to construct a URL with query parameters. However, there are some differences between the two methods.

The **queryParams** approach is used with the Angular **Router** module to construct URLs that contain query parameters. It is a convenient way to construct URLs that can be used with the **RouterLink** directive or the navigate method of the **Router** module. This approach is more suitable for navigation within the Angular application.

On the other hand, the **HttpParams** approach is used to construct URLs that can be used to make HTTP requests. It is a part of the Angular **HttpClient** module. This approach is more suitable for making HTTP requests to an external server.

Both approaches have their own advantages and use cases. If you are constructing URLs for navigation within your Angular application, you should use the **queryParams** approach. If you are constructing URLs for making HTTP requests to an external server, you should use the **HttpParams** approach.

In your specific example, if you are navigating to a page within your Angular application, you should use the **queryParams** approach. If you are making an HTTP request to an external server, you should use the **HttpParams** approach.